# PostgreSQL-how to select jsonb column array object values

Tags: json, postgresql

I facing one issues about select the jsonb column value.  I want to display the check in  and out time data when the day is equal to Monday. I tried to use

```
SELECT name, dayp -> 'days' ->> 'Monday'
FROM  attendanceprofile, 
      jsonb_array_elements(daysprofile) as dayp;
```

cannot get the value.

The value  inside the  jsonb column  is

```
[ {
        "days": {
            "Monday": {
                "checkin": "7:00",
                "checkout": "18:00"
            },
            "Tuesday": {
                "checkin": "5:00",
                "checkout": "16:00"
            }
        }
    } ]
```

Comment: Your JSONB value is an array, so you would need to access by element, but perhaps it isn't supposed to be an array at all.

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: Postgres Version 10

Comment: Is it always the first element in the array you want to look at? What if your array has more elements?

Comment: No. Depand on today day for display checkin and checkout times

Comment: If you always have a single element, then why an array to begin with?

Comment: you are right. I will remove the array from begin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always have a single element (or you always want this from the first element), you can pick those values using the "path operator" `#>>`

```
SELECT name, 
       daysprofile #>> '{0,days,Monday,checkin}' as checkin,
       daysprofile #>> '{0,days,Monday,checkout}' as checkout
FROM  attendanceprofile
```